# What does "|=" mean

Tags: c#, syntax

Context:

```
 private bool AllowMoveEventProcessing(float time)
     {
         bool allow = Input.GetButtonDown (m_HorizontalAxis);
         allow |= Input.GetButtonDown (m_VerticalAxis);
         allow |= (time > m_NextAction);
         return allow;
     }
```

As found in:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/782423/unity-46-ui-restrict-eventsystem-only-to-keyboard.html

Thank you very much!

Comment: `x |= y` is a shortcut for `x = x | y`.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx

Comment: @DrKoch _Inefficient_ might be a more _constructive_ adjective for the _sugar syntax_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That operator performs a bitwise OR operation and assigns the result back to `allow`. It's the equivalent of:

```
bool allow = Input.GetButtonDown(m_HorizontalAxis);
allow = allow | Input.GetButtonDown(m_VerticalAxis);
allow = allow | (time > m_NextAction);
return allow;
```

Honestly it doesn't make any sense and will perform unnecessary work since the operations will not short-circuit. It would be much easier to understand as (unless, of course, the code relies on side-effects of the method calls being run which is poor design as well):

```
return Input.GetButtonDown(m_HorizontalAxis) ||
    Input.GetButtonDown(m_VerticalAxis) ||
    time > m_NextAction;
```

Comment: @user2615897 - The OP specifically asked about C# not C/C++.

Comment: It is not "bitwise" when used on type `bool`. It is simply "or".

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - It is most certainly still a bitwise operator. It's just acting on a single bit. It still behaves completely differently than the logical or operator.

Comment: OK, it is a terminology discussion. In the official C# specification we have the subsection [Boolean logical operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691309.aspx) which is about the non-circuiting operators used on `bool`. They call them "logical". In the MSDN C# Reference there is the page [|= Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw.aspx) from which I quote: *The | operator performs a bitwise logical OR operation on integral operands and logical OR on bool operands.*

Comment: The operators `&&` and `||` are officially called [Conditional logical operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691310.aspx). So both "Boolean logical operators" and "conditional logical operators" are "logical". This is the official terminology.

Answer (score 0):

That operator is a bitwise OR.

A bitwise OR takes two bit patterns of equal length and performs the logical inclusive OR operation on each pair of corresponding bits. The result in each position is 1 if the first bit is 1 or the second bit is 1 or both bits are 1; otherwise, the result is 0.

Comment: It is not "bitwise" when used on type `bool`. It is simply "or".